# While Loop in Python 3 using lists and if-statement for begginer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding (Python) and am trying to learn loops. I have had some difficulty with a little complex while and for loops. Here I'm trying to create a function and use the while loop. Could I get some ideas on how to fix this code and get some explaintion on what i did wrong?

What I'm trying to achieve with this code is that I have some numbers stored in a list which are secret. And until the user doesn't type in one of these numbers the loop will continue asking. As soon as the user types in one of the numbers, the loop will exit preferibly without using exit() from sys.

```
def hell_hole():
 print("You have just fallen through the hell hole.")
 print("You must guess the right number to stop falling otherwise this program will keep repeating.")
 print("The right numbers are between 1 - 10 ")
 password = [4,9,8]

  while True:
    typed_in = input("What is the passing code?\n> ")
    if typed_in != password:
        print("Wrong, try again!")
    elif typed_in == password:
        print("Well done! You have stopped falling.")
    else:
        print("Say what?")
```

I know that this problem can be solved if i changed the if-statment to this:

```
  while True:
    typed_in = input("\nWhat is the passing code?\n> ")

    if "4" in typed_in or "8" in typed_in or "9" in typed_in:
        print("Well done! You have stopped falling.")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Wrong, try again!")
```

But I want to try to fix the inital code if possible.

Comment: instead of `exit()` try `break`

Comment: "I know that this problem can be solved if i changed the if-statment ... But I want to try to fix the inital code if possible." I don't understand; what do you mean by fixing it, if you don't mean making a change that solves the problem? Do you just want a better understanding of why the original code doesn't work? Or what?

Comment: Yes sir! That's exactly my point! Thanks for clearing it up! :)

Comment: `if typed_in != password:` `typed_in` is a `str` where as `password` is a `list`, the condition will always be `True`.

Comment: Replace this: `typed_in = int(input("What is the passing code?\n> "))`

Comment: Instead of `if typed_in != password:` use: `if typed_in not in password:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find below a working version of your code!
As it war already posted, if you want to check if the number entered by the user is IN the list of passwords, you can use the keyword in to do that. Furthermore, as the passwords are integer, you need to convert the input to this type.

In order to exit the while loop, you can use break, which allows you to exit the more nested loop!

Hope it helps!

```
def hell_hole():
print("You have just fallen through the hell hole.")
print("You must guess the right number to stop falling otherwise this program will keep repeating.")
print("The right numbers are between 1 - 10 ")
password = [4,9,8]

while True:
    typed_in = int(input("What is the passing code?\n> "))
    if typed_in in password:
        print("Well done! You have stopped falling.")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong, try again!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sys.exit()` you can use either `break` that will break your loop (here the `while` loop) or `return` that will return from your function.

Note that you can return a value from your function to use it out of it by using `return yourValue` but in your case it's not useful.

Also, an other useful control flow keyword is `continue` which allow you to skip an iteration of your loop. All those keywords work for both `while` and `for` loops.

To make your `if` statement better, i think you should either check if the password is one of the values you want it to be :

```py
if typed_in in ["4","8","9"]:
```

or check if one of those values are in the inputted string, just as you seem to do :

```py
if any(x in typed_in for x in ["4", "8", "9"]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` statement:

```py
password = ['4','9','8']
while True:
    typed_in = input("\nWhat is the passing code?\n> ")

    if typed_in in password:
        print("Well done! You have stopped falling.")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong, try again!")
```

Comment: maybe that's not what he want. he could just want a 4, 9 or 8 in his inputted string, just like what his code do.

Comment: His code does `"4" in typed_in or "8" in typed_in or "9" in typed_in`

Answer (score 0):

> note: you are trying to compare input (string) with whole list:
>
> > if typed_in != password

instead of that, check if input is in the list

> Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list:
>
> > if typed_in **in** password:

Also in your list (password = [4,9,8] )you have integers, input() is returning string

because of that you need to convert input into integer:

> **int**(input("What is the passing code?\n> "))

The **return statement** can be used as a kind of control flow. By putting one (or more) return statements in a function the return statement allows you to terminate the execution of a function

```
password = [4,9,8] # List of numbers 
while True:
    typed_in = int(input("What is the passing code?\n> "))
    if typed_in not in password: # Check if input is IN the list
        print("Wrong, try again!")
    elif typed_in in password: # Check if input is NOT in the list
        print("Well done! You have stopped falling.")
        return # Exit function
    else:
        print("Say what?")
```

Comment: same comment as the other answer

Comment: His code does `"4" in typed_in or "8" in typed_in or "9" in typed_in`

Comment: He wants to fix the inital code where : password = [4,9,8] @Nenri

Comment: I'm not talking about that.

Comment: And you did you read his code ? Ok you are fixing 2 issues, but not the 3 that are in his post

Answer (score 0):

- Cast the user input to an `int`, since you're comparing it to an array of `int`
- Use `in` and `not in` to check whether the entered number is in `password`
- Use `break` instead of `exit()`. `break` will simply exit the `while` loop.

Working implementation:

```
while True:
        typed_in = int(input("What is the passing code?\n> "))
        if typed_in not in password:
                print("Wrong, try again!")
        elif typed_in in password:
                print("Well done! You have stopped falling.")
                break
        else:
                print("Say what?")
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55450907

Comment: Instead of telling what he should do, explain what he should do. Remember he's new to Python (also, same comment as other answers, your code isn't reproducing his)